# What features of yarn are not yet available in npm v5.0?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

npm v5.0 brings a lot of features currently present in yarn, including:

- installs `--save` by default
- `package-lock.json` will be automatically created (I assume the lock file ensures consistent installs)
- automatic fallback-to-offline mode

From my understanding, what yarn offers in addition is parallel downloads (therefore faster download time). I don't see that mentioned in the [npm blog post](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500). Apart from this, are there other benefits to still using yarn?

Comment: Anyone deciding between npm and yarn , look at this [github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17722)

Answer (score 7):

Yarn is still, as of writing, slightly faster than npm. Thomas Schaaf has produced a [comparison](https://github.com/thomaschaaf/npm-vs-yarn) based on performance which can be viewed directly [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZE5B4qJw1kNGMzjgslcWTuPYrpatzQJXSYMGNOhZ2ys/edit). Currently, Yarn beats npm on every measurement, although not by a large margin. That's probably from the parallel downloads and superior caching, although that's purely conjecture and I haven't done any digging in the source to find out why the timing is different.

However, what you lose in performance, you gain in compatibility. There are a few packages that don't install correctly with Yarn, such as [`semantic-ui`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-ui), so you'd need to use npm for that anyway.

Since npm is **the** canonical package manager for Node environments, most packages will have been tested to work with npm. The same can't be said for Yarn—it's still a relative outsider.

Overall, though, I think npm@5 is far better than its predecessors, and I think it'd be reasonable to "switch back" unless Yarn brings new features to the table, especially if compatibility with all packages is important to you.

Answer (score 2):

That's a good question!

Indeed `npm` was pushed to have all these features `yarn` offers. Now they are pretty much the same:

1. cache is totally rewritten, it even works offline
2. `--save` is enabled by default
3. `package-lock.json` locks your versions and it is not optional as it were with `npm shrinkwrap`

`npm@5` also made a good progress at speed, but `yarn` is still faster. Here are the simple figures. Let's test it with `vue-starter` which has around 850 packages to download. `npm`’s time was not bad at all with 42 seconds at the fresh run. When the cache is ready, it takes only 30 seconds to install everything.

Compared to `yarn`: 35 seconds without cache and 20 seconds with the cache in place. For me, this time gap was important enough to still use `yarn` as a primary tool.

Actually, I wrote an article which covers all these topics: https://medium.com/wemake-services/is-yarn-still-a-thing-3c6886410c83